# D3 collapsible force layout d3.js: how to load json data without scrambling figure?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I'm struggling to read some json file on every 1 minute, without scramble the whole graphic and do the force method everytime, making the graphic fuzzy for who will be checking it, just updating some information inside the nodes, without any move after the FIRST stop or alpha(0).

Based on the same graphic below.

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html

[image]

Please, any help I appreciate.